# Is it possible to define two URLs for setcookie() in PHP?

Tags: php, cookies

I have three ways to connect to my webpage:
Extern ip, intern ip or domain name.

I'm learning about login "Remember me function" and don't really know much about it.

**SOME CODE**

```
//Define WEBSITE to use it in the cookie.
define ("WEBSITE",'123.12.1.123');

//set the cookie
$setc = setcookie(
    'remember',
     $selector.':'.base64_encode($authenticator),
     time() + 864000*7,
     '/',
     WEBSITE,
     false, // TLS-only set to true if u have a website on https://
     false  // http-only
);
```

I have now noticed that i can set a cookie when i log in if i go to the defined WEBSITE: `123.12.1.123`. But i cannot set a cookie if i use the internal ip: `192.12.1.123`

Is there a way to use multiple adressess? or how should i solve this?

Need more code? Just ask for it!

Comment: You could probably use an array and check if it's part of it, kind of a whitelist. I've never done anything like that but it sounds plausible.

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons, sites cannot set or retrieve cookies on other domains. The closest thing you can do is make the cookie available to all subdomains of a single domain.

Answer (score 0):

After a night sleep i thought out a very easy way to solve this:

```
//WICH URL IS BEING USED?
if($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == "123.12.1.1"){
    define ("WEBSITE",'123.12.1.1');  
}
else if($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == "123.12.1.2"){
    define ("WEBSITE",'123.12.1.2');  
}
```

Comment: You are just redefining a constant based on the IP accessed, that has nothing to do with cookies. By setting a cookie with one domain, it will not be sent to a website using a different domain.